# How to highlight the edges in surface3d plot of rgl package in R

Tags: r, rgl

I created a 3d plot with rgl in R like this:

```
persp3d(log2(x), log2(y), z, col=color, ticktype="detailed", xlab="filesize [kb]", ylab="record size [kb]", zlab="speed [b/s]", axes=TRUE, back="lines")
```

Now I want to highlight all edges by black lines. This would basically be the same as drawing a wireframe model over the surface. But I can't find a method in the rgl package that can do the job. The best I found is `grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))` but that highlights only certain edges that I see from behind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the picture of the plot so far https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1aTk.png

Best,
Loddi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
surface3d(log2(x), log2(y), z,  back="lines")
surface3d(log2(x), log2(y), z,  front="lines")
```

See also `?rgl.material` for parameters available

Comment: That worked! Just to clarify for other R beginners like me: You need to execute these two lines exactly as written above after you executed the persp3d() command in my initial question to achieve the wireframe look on top of the colored surface.